# Keyboard shift key bug on Lenovo Thinkpad

Tags: laptop, keyboard, thinkpad

For some days now, I have a problem with my Lenovo Thinkpad T470p keyboard.
Before all : I've already updated drivers and shutdown my computer.

Here are the problems :

- The light of the *caps lock* key is like 50% lighted up in permanence (see the photo). Of course, before, the light was off.
- When I hold the *shift* key and then press the space bar, it doesn't work.
- When I hold the *shift* key, and then press letters, some append 2 letters. For example, pressing *shift* + *B* appends "BT", *shift* + *T* appends "BT", *shift* + *Y* appends "NY", *shift* + *N* appends "NY".

It seems to be the only keys that have a problem.

The caps lock key in its normal state (abnormally 50% lighted up):

[image: Image: The caps lock key in its normal state (abnormally 50% lighted up)]

The caps lock key in its uppercase state (normal 100% lighted up):

[image: Image: The caps lock key in its uppercase state (normal 100% lighted up)]

Have you an idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: Try booting into the UEFI/BIOS and see if the problem exists there: this will eliminate any OS-related problems, including any form of virus infection.

Comment: It doesn't seem so :l Light still light up.

Comment: In that case, it's probably a hardware problem. Does that model have a removable battery? If so, shut down, remove the power plug and the battery, and leave completely unpowered for at least 30 seconds. This may clear any lingering hardware settings; otherwise, it's a repair job.

Comment: I've tried what you propose. Unfortunately, this seem to be a pure hardware problem... Thank you for your help anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the advices given by @AFH :

> Try booting into the UEFI/BIOS and see if the problem exists there: this will eliminate any OS-related problems, including any form of virus infection.

AND

> Remove the power plug and the battery, and leave completely unpowered for at least 30 seconds.

... the fact is : it is a pure **hardware problem** with the keyboard.